# pycryptodome equivalent C# RSA.SignHash?

Tags: python, c#, rsa, python-cryptography

Hello i'm trying to port some RSA encryption code from a C# application to python using python https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/

But my problem is i'm stuck on this line

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
 
result = RSA.SignHash(testData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
```

using python i'm trying this

```
with open('key.pem', 'r') as f:
    private_key = RSA.import_key(f.read())
    h = SHA256.new(bytes(testData))
    signature = pkcs1_15.new(private_key).sign(h)
```

I tried to make a unit test comparing the two functions using an example byte array

```
testData = bytes(b'\x5b\xd4\x08\xae\x4f\x80\x5d\x77\xc4\x4e\xc8\x23\x63\x82\x79\x17\xad\x75\x3a\x2b\x2f\xa6\x80\xb1\x31\x74\x19\x8c\x29\x80\x38\x49')
```

But the resulting output(result & signature variable) with length of 128 is not the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: @Topaco It looks like pycryptodome only offers a method to sign hashes and not data directly, Or am I missing something obvious?
https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html

I cannot modify the  C# program as it is being used so I can only replicate what it is already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by switching pythonlibrary from "python cryptodome" to "rsa"
https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/usage.html#signing-and-verification

The interesting code from above link:

```
(1)message = 'Go left at the blue tree'.encode()
(2)hash = rsa.compute_hash(message, 'SHA-1')
(3)signature = rsa.sign_hash(hash, privkey, 'SHA-1')
```

This library had splitted the "sign" functon into two parts so I basically skipped doing step (2) and it worked for me.